# Python list of comprehension, lambda function

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

I have this old version:

```
 for item in items:
     if not [True for key, value in items if a = b and c = d]:
         if fail:
            return False
         else:
            ...
```

But now I added more *if* conditions and an assignment.

```
  for item in things:
        for key, value in items:
             if a == b and c == b:
                sth = something
                if sth in bananas:
                    ...
```

How do I now include the *if* fail and *else* statement from the first version?

Is it still possible to use list of comprehensions in the second version, which is longer?
Would a lambda function maybe help here, or would I have to write a separate helper function?

Comment: `return not fail and sth in bananas`

Comment: The indentation is inconsistent (3, 4, 5, and 6 spaces). This is Python, after all.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code will never reach the end of the loop `for key, value in items` when the condition is met, you can add your `if fail: ...` code right after that loop (same indentation level).

There are some additional caveats but without more precision on bananas, fail and something, I can't tell you what other issues might come up (e.g. what happens when `sth` is not in `bananas` ?)

Answer (score 0):

To include the if fail and else statement from the first version, you can use an if statement inside the inner loop. For example:

```
for item in things:
  for key, value in items:
    if a == b and c == d:
      sth = something
      if sth in bananas:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

In this case, the if fail statement will be executed if the value of sth is not in the list bananas. Otherwise, the else statement will be executed and the function will return True.

You can still use list comprehensions in the second version of your code. For example:

```
def find_bananas(things, items):
  return [True for item in things
          for key, value in items
          if a == b and c == d and sth in bananas]
```

A lambda function would not help in this case, because you need to check multiple conditions.